# I wanted to run this command - pip3 install rarfile. but it did not work and give the following result

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, vagrant

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/rarfile-4.0.dist-info'

Storing debug log for failure in /home/vagrant/.pip/pip.log

I tried the code 'pip3 install rarfile', 'install rarfile pyfiglet py-term'. but it didn't work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+Errno+13+Permission+denied

Answer (score 0):

try giving the root access to the terminal, by using

`sudo` command

Comment: Thanks all, it worked but I need extra advice - I typed 'python3 zydra.py'. the outcome was like this: File "zydra.py", line 5, in <module>
    import rarfile  # need unrar tools
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/rarfile.py", line 946
    warnings.warn(f"Windows junction not supported - {info.filename}", UnsupportedWarning)

Comment: You can upgrade the python version to 3.7, it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your operating system is requiring admin permissions to run that command.
If you are running a Unix (Mac or Linux) try running:

```
sudo pip3 install rarfile
```

It should then prompt you for your admin password.

If you are interested in learning more about the subject this might be a valuable resource. [unix-linux-privileged-management-should-you-sudo](https://www.beyondtrust.com/blog/entry/unix-linux-privileged-management-should-you-sudo)

`sudo` at the beginning of the command will allow you to run as a superuser. I would not recommend using the `su` alternative if you're not comfortable with the risks.